# Movements in a Hexagon

Tags: geometry, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I don't know how to start this problem. I have tried to find a way to make it numerical or take it to another subject but I couldn't. The problem is this:

Imagine you have a seed in every vertex of a Hexagon. In each turn you can pick two and move them one vertex but in opposite ways. Prove that it is not possible to have them all in only one vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  If you pick a vertex and add up the clockwise distances to all the seeds at the start, what do you get?  How can the sum change when you move two seeds?